# Why wasn't the universe destroyed at the end of Journey's End?

Tags: doctor-who

In the episode Journey's End, Davros (in *this* universe) creates the Crucible and reality bomb to destroy this universe and every other. In the episode they are foiled by the human Doctor and the DoctorDonna, the planets are restored and everyone's home in time for tea.

But in the episode Doomsday, the Tenth Doctor explained to Jackie Tyler that "every single decision we make creates a parallel existence", so why wasn't a parallel universe created where either Martha activated the Osterhagen Key, Jack never blew the warp star, or Donna perished in the fire of the Crucible? Surely then Davros would have succeeded. Would that and every other universe have been destroyed?

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! Feel free to take the [Science Fiction & Fantasy tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand our site better. You can also visit [How to ask a good question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve your question by editing it. Also, use >! to create spoiler quotes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only two not purely speculative answers can be "the doctor is lying" and "Timey Whimey ..."

Comment: Maybe Davros can never succeed. His failure is a fixed point in time or some such.

Comment: I think the main idea is that either the Reality Bomb only ever existed in one Universe, or that its activation failed in every Universe it existed in.

Comment: In accordance with the theory of "what the hell, it sounds cool", assume that for every universe in which there exists a Davros to pull off such a plot, there must also exist an equal and opposite Doctor who counters said plot.

Answer (score 2):

**The multiversal destruction isn't something Davros can pull off on his own.**

Davros's Reality Bomb apparently uses technobabble physics to define some waveform which eliminates all matter, and his plot was to build a multi-planet engine that continuously produced such a wave to destroy everything but the Daleks.  Allowing that there's probably a universe in which Davros was allowed to construct and trigger such a device - and there probably was, given we see an alternate timeline where the stars start going out in *Turn Left* - it doesn't appear to cross over into the Doctor's universe at all.

The plot in *Journey's End* however, takes place in the Medusa Cascade, a bent-up region of space that contains a rift allowing Davros to spread the annihilation wave through all possible realities (or so he says).  We know that all possible realities includes the parallel world (Pete's World) Rose got trapped in from *Doomsday*, because the Doctor is able to drop her off there when all is said and done with Davros.  We don't know if Davros is really able to back up his claims though - reality hopping isn't well quantified other than the Doctor mentioning it was easier to do when Gallifrey ran everything.  Certainly Davros intended to force the rift as wide open as he could to wipe out plenty of everything, and certainly more than one universe would have been destroyed.  Rifts have two side though, and the Doctor has made a habit of closing them wherever he can (except Cardiff, apparently).

So if there is a bleak pocket of nowhere in the multiverse where a version of Davros has succeeded in turning on a Reality Bomb, and also having a rift handy nearby to throw it through... it has likely been stopped from affecting the Doctor's universe by sealing the Medusa Cascade rift from this side once our Davros was stopped.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the entire multiple universes thing was just an excuse to let Rose back into the plot, but this is the only speculation that makes sense to my mind.