# Doesn't Rick and Morty's premise preclude its own existence?

Tags: rick-and-morty

*Rick and Morty* takes place in an infinite multiverse with infinite variety, and it is possible to travel between realities.

If this is actually an infinite multiverse, then surely every imaginable possibility exists, and it is possible that a being wants to destroy all life in C-137 (Rick and Morty's home dimension), and has the capability to do it.

**So how can Rick and Morty be alive at all?**

Comment: There will also be an infinite number of multiverses where Rick and Morty prevent the universe-killing madman before he can execute his evil plan

Comment: Very similar question from a completely different franchise: [Why wasn't the universe destroyed at the end of Journey's End?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/162195/31394)

Comment: Sounds like the start of a beautiful lifelong research journey.

Comment: This should be reopened as it was directly answered in the show (the infinite curve that Evil Morty escapes from).

Comment: @TheAsh - Reopened and answered in-canon

Comment: @Valorum thanks. I wish I got a shot at it, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An infinite multiverse of infinite possibilities includes *and* precludes all eventualities. This includes an infinite number of C-137s that are destroyed, an infinite number ruled by Jerrys, an infinite number that can't be accessed and an infinite number that have Ricks that never discover interdimensional travel.

In a fiction that is based on this, there are infinite R&Ms who never make it off Earth, and infinite R&Ms who have the adventures that we watch. In fact, there are also an infinite number of variations on the adventures we watch, as well as an infinite number we'll never see, and infinite variations on those.

The benefit/trouble (depends on your outlook) with infinite possibilities is that there's a 100% chance of every event occuring (if the R&M multiverse truly is infinite, which it so far seems to be). This means there's a 100% chance of a C-137 which has the adventures we are able to watch. The reason we don't watch any of the other guys is that two dead cartoon characters being broadcast for half an hour doesn't make great television.

Of course, if R&Ms rules apply to our own reality, then there is a universe out there which does broadcast two dead cartoon characters for half an hour. In this universe, you've asked a variation of *Sci-Fi and Fantasy SE* why we don't see them alive, since the premise of the show includes an infinite number of R&Ms who do have adventures. Unfortunately, no one responded, as a Vogon Constructor Fleet vaporised the Earth shortly after your alternative counterpart asked this question. That's infinite possibilities for you.

Answer (score 4):

Rick realised this and took care of it by creating the [Central Finite Curve](https://rickandmorty.fandom.com/wiki/Central_Finite_Curve), a walled garden of realities in which Rick is always the central character. Rick defines this as any reality with a

> "working ecosystem along with their own functional Rick entity"...
>
> [image]

...but Evil Morty sees it as more of a protection/defence mechanism set up by Rick to protect himself from having to deal with the reality of him probably not being the smartest entity in the whole universe.

> Do you know what the Central Finite Curve is? They built a wall around
> infinity, separated all the infinite universes from all the infinite
> universes where he's the smartest man in the universe. Every version
> of us has spent every version of all of our lives in one infinite
> crib, built around an infinite fucking baby.
>
> [image]

One of the key elements of Evil Morty's story arc is that he escapes the curve and spends his time in a chaotic reality where portal travel is rampant.